# Java read upon opening program

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton

In Java (swing) how would you read from a file upon opening the program. I can read from a file by pressing a JButton and i wanted the information to be read into the array as soon as the program is opened up without having to press a button

Comment: Your question really doesn't make any sense. If you know how to read a file when you click a button, why would the code to read the file be any different when you start the program?

Answer (score 4):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    File f = new File(filepath)
    BufferedReader b = new Bufferedreader(f.getInputStream);
    String line = "";
    while((line = b.readLine())!=null)
    {
         // do something
    }
    // continue ...
}
```

This would read the file first when the java code is run.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke a thread in main method that will read file contents ans store contents in array.